# How to add scroll option in <h:outputText/>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dialog that contain

```
<p:dialog id="sqlDialog" 
          widgetVar="sqlWidgetVar"
          header="SQL" 
          width="800"
          position="center"
          minimizable="true"
          maximizable="true"
          appendToBody="true"
          dynamic="true">
    <h:outputText id="sql" 
                  escape="false" 
                  value="#{bean.sql}" 
                  style="color: green"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Since the text is very long I need to add a scroll option

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS to make it a block element with fixed dimensions and an overflow.

```
<h:outputText ... styleClass="sqlDialogText" />
```

with

```css
.sqlDialogText {
    display: block;
    width: 600px; /* Optional, depends otherwise on parent. */
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    color: green;
}
```

Alternatively, just give the dialog a fixed height.

```
<p:dialog ... height="300">
```

Note that this has nothing to do with JSF. It's just a HTML/CSS/JS code generator. The `<h:outputText>` generates a HTML `<span>` element. You just have to alter the CSS accordingly for the look'n'feel.

Comment: thanks,Is there a way to make the scroll height dynamic so if I will maximize or minimize the dialog window the scroll height will be adjust ?

Comment: @angus That is a question on it's own. Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. If you use the search function of stackoverflow I'm sure you can find an answer tagged with CSS ;-)

Comment: Give the dialog a fixed height instead.